# alignat not correctly aligning

Tags: amsmath, align

I have the following code:

```
\begin{alignat}{4}
    \sum_{r}\sum_{p} & X_{i,m,r,p}       & = d_m                          \quad & \forall i, m\\
\sum_{q=0}^{d_{m}-1} & X_{i,m,r,(p+q)}   & = d_m \times \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} \quad & \forall i, m, r, p\\
            \sum_{p} & \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} & \leq 1                         \quad & \forall i, m, r
\end{alignat}
```

Which should show three lines with the X's aligned, the RHS aligned, and the `\forall` conditions on the right aligned.

What I'm getting, instead, is something like this:

[image: alignat problem]

I use `alignat` in my other LaTeX document, and it works perfectly. I have no idea what I've done wrong, but I can't find anything different in the way I've used `alignat` in this document compared to my other one.

Comment: The rule for alignment is `rlrlrl…`. If you want to have two columns aligned left or right use `&&` between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're short some alignment tabs, as mentioned in comment by Qrrbrbirlbel. Here's the proper usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{4}
    \sum_{r}\sum_{p} & X_{i,m,r,p}       & = d_m                          \quad & \forall i, m\\
\sum_{q=0}^{d_{m}-1} & X_{i,m,r,(p+q)}   & = d_m \times \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} \quad & \forall i, m, r, p\\
            \sum_{p} & \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} & \leq 1                         \quad & \forall i, m, r
\end{alignat}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    \sum_{r}\sum_{p} & X_{i,m,r,p}       && = d_m                          \quad && \forall i, m\\
\sum_{q=0}^{d_{m}-1} & X_{i,m,r,(p+q)}   && = d_m \times \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} \quad && \forall i, m, r, p\\
            \sum_{p} & \hat{X}_{i,m,r,p} && \leq 1                         \quad && \forall i, m, r
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

Consider reading about the AMS alignment environments in Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf). Specifically, section **25 align environments** (p 43 onwards).